# What endpoint in the Instagram API do I use to retrieve data from followed accounts such as the amount of followers they have?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I want to create an app that can show you the amount of followers and the amount of accounts followed by particular user that your account follows. Confusing I know....
What endpoint do I use to retrieve such data from followed accounts?

I have tried reading through the Instagram API documentation but it only shows a small amount of endpoints to be used. I know there are much more endpoints to be used, for example by apps such as "Unfollowers" where it can specifically list the accounts that you follow and that don't follow you back.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following endpoint of the unofficial Instagram API

https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query/?query_hash=c76146de99bb02f6415203be841dd25a&variables={"id":"**USER_ID**","include_reel":true,"fetch_mutual":true,"first":10}

to retrieve the first **10** followers.

The data of the followers is in the *edges* array:

`data.user.edge_followed_by.edges`

Since the API limits the data per request, you should make any subsequent requests as follows:

https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query/?query_hash=c76146de99bb02f6415203be841dd25a&variables={"id":"**USER_ID**","include_reel":true,"fetch_mutual":true,"first":10,"after":"**END_CURSOR**"}

where **end_cursor** is the value in the response:

`data.user.edge_followed_by.page_info.end_cursor`

Then for each of the users you follow can extract their **USER_ID** and use:

https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/users/**USER_ID**/info/

to get the count of each user.

Please note that you need to supply all the cookies for `instagram.com` for the requests. You can find a full list in the developer tools of the browser.

`document.cookie` does not deliver all the cookies, since some are sent automatically by the browser, so please look them up in the developer tools.

Hope it helps !

Comment: how can i use this without login?